# Average power of sound wave

Tags: waves, acoustics

Does average power of a sound wave depend on its wavelength? if no then why? please help because in my textbook it is given it doesn't but if in formula for av. power we replace v=(lambda)*(frequency) then it does.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends, as it does with many such questions in Physics, on what you consider to be kept constant.

Thus, the mean power crossing an area *A* in a medium of density $\rho$ may be written
$$P=A\ 2\pi^2\rho a^2  f^2 v$$
in which $a$ is the amplitude of particle oscillation, $f$ is the frequency of oscillation, and $v$ is the speed of the wave.

So we could say that the power is proportional to the square of the frequency and to the wave speed. Note that we're considering the wave amplitude as held constant.

But because $v=f \lambda,$ we could write our equation as
$$P=A\ 2\pi^2\rho a^2 v^3\ \times\ \frac{1}{\lambda^2}$$
So now the power seems to be proportional to the cube of the wave speed! Well, it is – if we consider the wavelength and amplitude as held constant!

And – to answer your specific question at long last – the power is inversely proportional to the wavelength squared as long as we keep $a,$ $\rho,$ and $v$ constant. Keeping the last two constant simply requires one to keep the same medium: the speed of sound is usually a constant for a given medium, over a wide range of amplitudes and frequencies. But I'm not sure how to keep $a$ constant!

[A simpler example of the same sort of thing is the power dissipated in a resistor. We can write
$$P=\frac{V^2}{R}\ \ \ \ \text{but also}\ \ \ \ P=I^2R$$
So is the power inversely proportional to the resistance or directly proportional to the resistance? It depends whether you're holding the voltage constant or the current.]